# Convert String to its Unicode code point

Tags: java, unicode

Assuming I have a string foo = "This is an apple"

The Unicode code point equivalent will be

"        `\\x74\\x68\\x69\\x73.......... \\x61\\x70\\x70\\x6c\\x65` "

> ```
>    T    h    i   s  ............. a    p    p    l   e
> ```

How do I convert from String foo

to

String "        `\\x74\\x68\\x69\\x73.......... \\x61\\x70\\x70\\x6c\\x65` "

Comment: Here is a way to do it via each individual character... may steer you in the right direction: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Convertsthestringtotheunicodeformat.htm

Comment: Shouldn't the first part of your converted string be \\x54?

Comment: This might help: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/ConvertintoHexadecimalnotationofUnicode.htm

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
        public static String generateUnicode(String input) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(input.length());
            for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {

                b.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) c));

            }
            return b.toString();
        }
```

Comment: there is no such thing as `UTF-16` codepoint. Unicode codepoints are individual values of characters. `UTF-16` is an encoding of the codepoint using at least 2 bytes. Code points in the low planes are encoded using their exact values. (hence the common confusion between the 2). Supplementary planes use surrogate pairs, which make things a little more complicated

Comment: this will work in most cases. The case where it will not work is if there are surrogate pairs used (very rare characters only), because in the BMP (basic multilingual plan), the encoding define by utf-16 is simply to use the plain codepoint on 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working code snippet to make the conversion:

```
public class HexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testStr = "hello日本語 ";

        System.out.println(stringToUnicode3Representation(testStr));
    }

    private static String stringToUnicode3Representation(String str) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
            result.append("\\u").append(Integer.toHexString(charArr[i] | 0x10000).substring(1));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }   
}
```

That display:

> \u0068\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u0020

If you want to get rid of the extra zeros you elaborate it as described [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/Convertsthestringtotheunicodeformat.htm).

Here another version to do the conversion, by passing `"This is an apple"` you get

> \u54\u68\u69\u73\u20\u69\u73\u20\u61\u6e\u20\u61\u70\u70\u6c\u65

by using:

```
private static String str2UnicodeRepresentation(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int cp = Character.codePointAt(str, i);
        int charCount = Character.charCount(cp);
        //UTF characters may use more than 1 char to be represented
        if (charCount == 2) {
            i++;
        }
        result.append(String.format("\\u%x", cp));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```